# I want to download file from url in node.js?

Tags: node.js, http, http-status-code-403

```
const BC = require('nse-bhavcopy');
const options = {
 dir: "./",
 headers : {
   'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'
 }
};
const request = new BC(options);
request
  .download({
    month : "JAN",
    year : 2008
  })
  .then(data=>console.log(data))
  .catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

I want to download this whole month of reports but I can't able to download it. But when I go to browser and tries to download it works perfectly.

So, I read on internet and some other answers they told to mention user agent also, but can't able to do it. It shows message as Access Denied. Please help to resolve this issue? And it shows status-code as 403.

Any ideas is appreciated!

I am getting something like this:

```
[ { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 01JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 02JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 03JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 04JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 05JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 06JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 07JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 08JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 09JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 10JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 11JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 12JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 13JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 14JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 15JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 16JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 17JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 18JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 19JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 20JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 21JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 22JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 23JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 24JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 25JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 26JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 27JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 28JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 29JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 30JAN2008' },
  { message: 'Access Denied: for the file on date 31JAN2008' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your dir location to `path.join(__dirname,'')`.

Try this.

```
const BC = require('nse-bhavcopy');
const path = require('path');
const options = {
 dir: path.join(__dirname,'')
};
const request = new BC(options);
request
  .download({
    month : "JAN",
    year : 2008
  })
  .then(data=>console.log(data))
  .catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Comment: Issue is not with path, it's with the permissions. Because error is showing as Asscess Denied from server, rather than path which you mentioned.

Comment: Then provide permission to directory where you want to download file. `chmod 766 {folder_name}`